# please my Pthon, kivymd App closes immediately after loading on andriod

Tags: google-colaboratory, python-3.7, specifications, kivymd, buildozer

i want to convert my pyhon kivymd code to APK but it closes immediately after loading , i dont know
where am getting it wrong ,i compiled using google Colab,
i have bn on this compiling process since 4months ago..
please help as am new to python coding

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.toast import toast
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivy.lang import Builder
from datetime import date, datetime
from kivy.metrics import dp
import sqlite3

if platform == "android":
from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
request_permissions(\[Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE\])

class CarApp(MDApp):

my buildozer requirements are 
requirements = python3,kivy==2.1.0,kivymd==1.1.1,Pillow,Kivy-Garden,numpy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after so much effort.    Updated my requirements by adding android and replacing kivy-garden with kivy_garden

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).